# Sending local file through a Webhook to Discord

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, discord

I am trying to send a local file to Discord using a Webhook. I am using C# and .NET 3.5. My code is:

```
JObject jWebhook = new JObject
{
    { "content", "Test:" },
    { "files", "image.jpg" }
};

return jWebhook;
```

This successfully sends the content message `Test:`, but doesn't upload the file. My `ContentType` is `multipart/form-data` as the Discord API asks for [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message).
I've also tried looking at this [documentation](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/file.html), but again it still isn't working.

Comment: You can't simply use a string for `"files"` and actually expect it to upload `image.jpg`

Comment: Consider using the discord.net api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296205/c-sharp-discord-bot-upload-local-image

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FrankerZ, but this isn't a Discord BOT, it is a separate app. Currently I am using WebClient and the following code to actually send the https://hastebin.com/cipisequza.cs