# C# Discord.net Add File as Image to Embed

Tags: c#, discord.net

How can I add a local file to my Embed as image.

I don't want to upload it to imgur or anything and get the URL. That doesn't work for the project due to changing images.

My code right now:

```cs
                var emb = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .WithColor(Color.Blue)
                    .WithTimestamp(DateTime.Now)
                    .WithTitle(rarity)
                    .WithDescription($"{Context.User.Username} dropped a card!")
                    .WithImageUrl($"attachment://{path}")
                    .Build();

                await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(path, null, false, emb);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Discord Bot - Upload Local Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296205/c-sharp-discord-bot-upload-local-image)

Comment: @HanletEscaño It does not. I don't want to send the image separately, I want to send it in  the embed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

                var emb = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .WithImageUrl($"attachment://{filename}")
                    .Build();

                await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(path, null, false, emb);
```

The `Path.GetFileName` made it possible for me in combination with `attachment://{filename}`